# Converting ArcMap DynamicValue rules to Attribute Rules in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-rules, attribute-assistant

I am slowly migrating my work processes from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro.  One of the hold-ups for me is that I have a large table of Attribute Assistant rules in ArcMap that make inputting of utility data so much quicker and easier.  My understanding is that ArcGIS Pro's Attribute Rules are the new and (not quite) improved version of Attribute Assistant and the DynamicValue table.

It seems one of the biggest changes is that instead of a single table with all the rules, including wildcard rules, the rules are now set at a feature class level.  Add to that the rules and syntax aren't the same...

So far I have been unable to find a tool to quickly and easily migrate my old rules to the new format.  Even one that did them partially, or only 80% of them, would be great.

What is the best way to migrate the DynamicValue table into Attribute Rules?  Is there an easy-to-follow guide on doing so?  Or am I going to have to figure out the difference for every rule and write an arcpy script to attempt to migrate them for me?